# Using https POST for transaction but don't understand how to transition from MD5 to transHashSHA2 in my code

Tags: md5, sha256, authorize.net

I got an email today saying:

> Authorize.Net is phasing out the MD5 based transHash element in favor of the SHA-256 based transHashSHA2. The setting in the Merchant Interface which controls the MD5 Hash option will be removed by the end of January 2019, and the transHash element will stop returning values at a later date to be determined.
>
> We have identified that you have this feature configured and may be relying on MD5 based transHash in transaction responses for verifying the sender is Authorize.Net.

I use the http POST method to submit my transaction and do the MD5 check on the response using a bit of C code that was written long ago. What should I do with my POST to transition and how to handle the 'transHasSHA2' stuff? Currently in C I am linking libssl and using the MD5_ functions.

Damn, I did this all so long ago, and a January 2019 deadline is awfully close!

Comment: Do I really even need to verify a transHash at all? Seems like a bit of overkill. Maybe just comment the MD5 stuff out?

Comment: What documentation do Authorize.net provide to help you to do this?

Comment: same I need to update in PHP.
Can anyone help who have done the same?
generating signature mean  - Do I need to avoid transaction id at my end for DPM.

currently in my application I use - 
API Login ID
Transaction Key
MD5 hash


for newer process what I will have to configure?

Answer (score 0):

The email sent by Authorze.Net included a link to a page that explains [how to transition to the new hash](https://developer.authorize.net/support/hash_upgrade/):

> ## Transaction Hash Upgrade Guide
>
> Authorize.Net is phasing out the MD5 based **transHash** element in favor of the SHA-512 based **transHashSHA2**. The setting
> in the Merchant Interface which controls the MD5 Hash option will be
> removed by the end of January 2019, and the **transHash** element will
> stop returning values at a later date to be determined.
>
> When you receive a transaction response from Authorize.Net, it
> includes the **transHashSHA2** element.  **transHashSHA2** contains
> the HMAC-SHA512 hash that Authorize.Net generated for the transaction.
> To use it, construct a HMAC-SHA512 hash using your Signature Key,
> converted to byte format, as the HMAC key, and a message constructed
> from your API Login ID, the transaction ID, and the transaction
> amount. Compare your hash result with **transHashSHA2**. If the two
> values match, the transaction response came from Authorize.Net.
>
> Note: The value of **transHashSHA2** will be null if you do not
> [generate the Signature Key](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/What-is-a-Signature-Key) first.
>
> To use the Signature Key to validate the value of **transHashSHA2**:
>
> **Step 1.** [Generate a Signature Key](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/What-is-a-Signature-Key) and store it in a secure location on your server.
>
> **Step 2.** Convert the Signature Key into a byte array.
>
> **Step 3.** Create a message string that starts with a caret ("^"), followed by the following three fields delimited by carets, and
> terminated with another caret:
>
> •    The API Login ID that you send in **createTransactionRequest** in
> the **name** element.
>
> •    The transaction ID that we send in **createTransactionResponse**
> in the **transId** element.
>
> •    The transaction amount that we send in
> **createTransactionResponse** in the **amount** element.
>
> For example, if your API Login ID is "ANet123", the value of
> **transId** is "20987654321", and the value of **amount** is "9.99", the message string would look like this:
>
> **^ANet123^20987654321^9.99^**
>
> **Step 4.** Use HMAC-SHA512 to hash the byte array form of the Signature Key from Step 2 with the message string from Step 3.
>
> **Step 5.** Compare the value of **transHashSHA2** with the output from the HMAC-SHA512 hash mentioned in Step 4.

Comment: i have tried to step-3 using my auth.net sandbox account. but in sandbox account transaction_id return 0 so every time my sha512 generate a same key because all request value are same. but sha2 is different every time in response from auth.net. So is there any other field i need to add in step-3 something like timestamp ?